# Eclipse Maven Update does not completely regenerate Eclipse project files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I am having **Maven** managed Java project in **Eclipse** (using the built in Maven integration of Eclipse Kepler/Luna). I observed that sometimes a Java component which is a dependency to another one is not found at runtime.

This sometimes could be resolved by removing the project form Eclipse, deleting the `.settings`, `.classpath` and `.project`files and reimport it to Eclipse.
I would expect that a simple `Maven -> Update` did the same but it does not.

Is this a known behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure the dependency does not have provided scope?

Comment: Yes, the scope was not set explicitely, so it is "compile" which is the default. That is not a problem. 
I think it might be due to the fact the the project was once imported into Eclipse as a pure Java project (not a Maven project) and then some settings of the former import remained. But even in that case I would expect "Maven -> Update" to completely recreate the Eclipse files.

Comment: m2eclipse is far from perfect, that's for sure. That being said: maven update only updates the dependencies. You need to do a maven -> update project configuration (I think in newer versions that has been renamed) to really sync the Eclipse project with the poms.